# Import One Worksheet from Multiple Excel Files into Multiple Access tables

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have about 200 Excel files that I would like to import into a single Access database and have a table for each file. Each Excel file has multiple worksheets, but the one that I would like to import is consistently named.

I have found some code for this, see: http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_Import.htm#ImpBrsFldFiles,
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dfea25ab-cd49-495c-8096-e3a7a1484f65/importing-multiple-excel-files-with-different-file-name-into-access-using-vba

Here is one of the pieces of code which I tried:

```
Option Compare Database

Sub ImportFromExcel()

End Sub

Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
Dim strTable As String, strBrowseMsg As String
Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean
    ' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
    ' has field names
blnHasFieldNames = True

strBrowseMsg = "C:\Users\fratep\Desktop\Long-term EWM Study Data Files\"
strPath = BrowseFolder(strBrowseMsg)
If strPath = "" Then
   MsgBox "No folder was selected.", vbOK, "No Selection"
   Exit Sub
End If

   ' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which
   ' the data are to be imported
strTable = "tablename"

strFile = Dir(strPath & "\*.xls")
  Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    strPathFile = strPath & "\" & strFile
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
        strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames

 ' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
 ' EXCEL file after it's been imported
 '       Kill strPathFile

   strFile = Dir()
 Loop



Sub ImportMultiExcels()

End Sub
```

from the 1st link above, but I can't seem to get them to do what I am looking for. Can anyone help me?

I am new to VBA, so am a little uncertain about editing the code.

Comment: What is the specific problem?  Can you import a single sheet into Access but not extend that to 200 sheets?  Or what?

Comment: Hi Hans,  Yes, as far as I can tell the Import Wizard only does one sheet at a time. Like I said I've found VBA scripts to perform the function, but for some reason I can't get them to work.

Comment: OK then show us your VBA which successfully imports a single sheet and describe the problems you're facing when trying to extend that to 200 sheets.

Comment: Also, I should add that I'm pretty new to VBA, so I do have a bit of trouble reading and customizing it to my situation. I did change the path names in the files, so that's not it.

Comment: Sorry, not using VBA to import single sheet, I'm using the Import Wizard. Is that my problem?

Comment: I'm unsure, Paul.  New to VBA is not a deal-killer.  But we need to see where you're having problems so we can figure out how to help.  Without seeing any code, I have no idea where to start.  :-(

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're able to use the Import Wizard to successfully import a worksheet into Access.  In that case, you should be able to use the [DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb214134%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to do the same thing from VBA code in your Access database.

The procedure below imports a single sheet named *XYZ Priority* as an Access table named *Import1*.

I used a constant for the sheet name because you said the target sheet has the same name in all the source workbook files.

I constructed the table name as *"Import"* plus *i*.  When you extend this to multiple workbooks, you can increment *i* after each import.  Or perhaps you have a different strategy for the table names; you didn't say.

I split the `TransferSpreadsheet` statement across several lines, and included the option names to (hopefully) make it easier to understand.

My worksheet includes column names, so I have `HasFieldNames:=True`

And my workbook was created with an older version of Excel. `SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9` works with this; you may need a different value for `SpreadsheetType`

```vb
Public Sub Demo_TransferSpreadsheet()
    Const cstrSheetName As String = "XYZ Priority"
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strTableName As String

    ' my workbook is located in the same folder as the Access db file
    strFileName = CurrentProject.Path & Chr(92) & "temp.xls"
    i = 1
    strTableName = "Import" & CStr(i)

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
        TransferType:=acImport, _
        SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
        Tablename:=strTableName, _
        FileName:=strFileName, _
        HasFieldNames:=True, _
        range:=cstrSheetName & "$"
End Sub
```

Comment: So how can I modify this code to do this for every excel file in a specified folder?

Comment: Please be patient with me. How do I specify the path leading to the CurrentProject? Sorry for such a dumb question, like I said, I'm a brand newb.

Comment: My workbook is located in the same folder as the Access db file which holds that VBA procedure.  So I used `CurrentProject.Path & Chr(92)` as a substitute for the actual folder path: C:\share\Access\  In your version of the code, use whatever method you're comfortable with to specify the folder piece.

Comment: Okay, sorry again, when I try to run the code it tells me that the Macros in this project are disabled. I tried to enable them and I keep getting the error message. I also closed and reopened the package and still the same thing happens. Any thoughts?

Comment: I just updated the answer ... *"VBA code in your Access database"*.  Are you trying to use VBA from an Excel workbook instead?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40530/discussion-between-paul-and-hansup)